# Don't show notification when playing audio in JS

Tags: javascript, audio

I play audio with this code snippet:

```
let audio = new Audio("notification.mp3");
audio.play()
```

It works but I don't want it do show the playing music notification. Is this possible? If yes please provide code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The Music note sign shown on the browser is controlled by the browser hence you cannot hide it. The badge is helpful for the users to figure out which tab is playing the sound.